# Trying to write to User class parse, masterkey is not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to update a field within the User class without being logged in as a user. From reading online and other responses people say I should use the 'masterkey' to do so. Here is my cloud code where I have added in the master key. The code is executed but when I go to my data browser the totalScore and predictions values are still the same and not updated to the new values.

```
Parse.initialize("key", "key");
Parse.Cloud.define("userUpdate", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  var publicReadACL = new Parse.ACL();
  publicReadACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

  request.object.setACL(publicReadACL);

  var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  var query = new Parse.Query(User);
  query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
  query.find({
   success: function(user) {

            user.set("totalScore", request.params.totalS);
            user.set("totalPredictions", request.params.totalG);
            user.save()

    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("f");
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've figured this out by now, but if you haven't...I would first say check to make sure that you're passing the "totalScore" and "totalPredictions" as numbers.  If you pass them as strings and Parse is expecting a Number, it won't update.  And generally, I believe it's best practice to query the user class as follows:

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(user.objectId, {
      success: function(userAgain) {
        userAgain.set("totalScore", totalScore);
        userAgain.save(null, {
          error: function(userAgain, error) {
            // This will error, since the Parse.User is not authenticated
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Then of course you'd still need to include the master key stuff etc...

Comment: This saved my life! I can't believe they don't mention it in the documentation